# Stargazer output in RMarkdown - What is my illegal charachter?

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, stargazer

I am running logistic regression models and try to print out the output with stargazer in RMarkdown. I have applied dcolumn in my setup, but I still get "*! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.*" when I try to knit the document to a pdf. I have tried to just copy in the LateX-code, but it also says I have an illegal character. Could someone help me to find the illegal character?

**RMarkdown file:**

````
title: "Tables and Figures"
author: "me"
date: "November 2019"
header_includes: - \usepackage{dcolumn}
output: pdf_documentclassoption: landscape




 ```   
 {r Regression results Q21 1, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

 Q21e_teaching99 <- glm(Q21e_teaching ~ Country + Field + typeposition + Gender + Age, data = 
 SurveyPHEC, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

 stargazer(Q21e_teaching99,  type="latex", align = TRUE)

 ```
````

LatexCode that this produces:

```
  length of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be 
  changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changed
 % Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at 
 fas.harvard.edu
 % Date and time: man., des 02, 2019 - 14.33.50
 % Requires LaTeX packages: dcolumn 
 \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \caption{} 
 \label{} 
 \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} } 
 \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Q21e\_teaching} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
CountryNorway & -0.255 \\ 
& (0.184) \\ 
& \\ 
CountryUnited Kingdom & 0.046 \\ 
& (0.195) \\ 
& \\ 
CountryNetherlands & 0.322^{**} \\ 
& (0.149) \\ 
& \\ 
CountryDenmark & 0.171 \\ 
& (0.165) \\ 
& \\ 
FieldPhysics & -0.109 \\ 
& (0.124) \\ 
& \\ 
typepositionSenior & 0.912^{***} \\ 
 & (0.119) \\ 
 & \\ 
GenderMale & 0.002 \\ 
 & (0.150) \\ 
 & \\ 
Age40 to 49 years & 0.283 \\ 
 & (0.179) \\ 
 & \\ 
Age50 to 59 years & 0.329^{*} \\ 
 & (0.185) \\ 
 & \\ 
Age60 years and more & 0.610^{***} \\ 
 & (0.192) \\ 
 & \\ 
Constant & -1.548^{***} \\ 
 & (0.217) \\ 
 & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{788} \\ 
Log Likelihood & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-326.114} \\ 
Akaike Inf. Crit. & \multicolumn{1}{c}{674.227} \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
length of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be 
changedlength 
of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changed
```

**R Markdown output**

! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

Comment: Can you show the complete .tex and .log files? If I guess a couple of packages, I can compile your code fragment

Comment: The header looks fishy. maybe a couple of linebreaks would be in order?

Comment: Thank you for the response. By headers, do you refer to "length of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be 
  changedlength of NULL cannot be changedlength of NULL cannot be changed"?

Comment: With headers I mean the stuff like `output: pdf_documentclassoption: landscape`

Comment: Ah, that is why I have some huge tables and have set the header to produce the pdf in landscape format.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: "output: pdf_documentclassoption: landscape" is just written so I get the pdf in landscape format

Comment: I understand *why* you want to write that, but I don't think the syntax is correct. At the very least a linebreak is missing

Comment: Try with this header: https://pastebin.com/PSkUURQ8

Comment: Thank you so much - with this header it worked!

Answer (score 5):

The error indicates that the `dcolumn` package is not loaded. The reason it is not loaded are multiple syntax errors in your yaml header.

The following header should load the package (note the added line breaks):

```
---
title: "Tables and Figures"
author: "me"
date: "November 2019"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn}    
classoption: landscape
---
```